# Web Api 2 Attribute Routes not loading in MSTest project

Tags: mstest, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am trying to create an integration test for a Web Api 2 route that uses Attribute Routing. I have 2 projects in the solution, a Web Api 2 project (self hosting for this example) with a controller containing the following route and a MSTest project to run the test.

Controller:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    Product[] products = new Product[]  
    {  
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 },  
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M },  
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M }  
    };

    [Route("products")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8080");

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        using (HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
        {
            server.OpenAsync().Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

The above route runs just fine when I hit it from a browser/fiddler while debugging the Web Api project. I have tried both self hosting and IIS and both work in this case.

In my MSTest project I configure the self host server like so:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8080");

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.EnsureInitialized();

        using (HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
        {
            server.OpenAsync().Wait();

            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:8080/products")).Result;
            var code = response.StatusCode;

            server.CloseAsync().Wait();
        }
    }
```

The route is always not found. Additionally config.Routes does not contain my route. I have tried implementing a custom IAssemblyResolver in an attempt to get MapHttpAttributeRoutes() to find the attribute enabled routes in the assembly containing the controllers but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*Simplified the test example

Comment: What does your global.cs look like?

Comment: included Global.asax.cs code. Is that what you meant? My understanding is that Application_Start() would never fire in the context of an MSTest project.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Now provide what WebApiConfig.Register looks like.

Comment: Can you provide your controller that you are trying to invoke? The declaration of the class and the function you want invoked.

Comment: Ok, I included WebApiConfig.Register

Comment: Included full controller at top of post. You will notice this is just a dummy test controller but exhibits the issue nicely. I should mention that the controller code and WebApiConfig code are from separate projects/solutions.

Comment: What happens if you change the route to `http://localhost:8080/products/products`?

Comment: you mean [Route("products/products")] ?

Comment: No, in your test program. Also try `http://localhost:8080/api/products/products

Comment: Tried changing both the Route attrib and client url separate and together. Still not found. Just to clarify I am trying to self host my web api inside my MSTest project for testing. (Making sure we are on the same page) :)

Comment: Yea, I do it all the time, it's pretty useful. The way you are configuring routes at the end of the WebApiConfig, kind of smells like the cause.

Comment: What happens if you comment out all the config.Routes.MapHttpRoute and replace it with 'config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );'. Then try the http://localhost:8080/api/products/products ?

Comment: Ok will try commenting it out for this test. You can see we are mixing attribute routing with the old template style.

Comment: I simplified the problem using a self host example which removes the dependency of a WebApiConfig. I get the same result. -Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Self Host Solution:

The issue here was resolved with a custom IAssemblyResolver. See: https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/CustomAssemblyResolverSample

Web Host Solution:

This one was a bit tricky. The call to config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes() in the WebApiConfig.Register() MUST be the first thing that executes against the config. I already had this call before we defined our standard template routes but there were two calls above it. config.EnableCors() and config.AddODataQueryFilter(). Once I move the call to MapHttpAttributeRoutes() above these two everything just started working. No custom IAssemblyResolver necessary.

Thanks to wbennet for the assistance!